# Can I create a build variant in my app-project to include a Wear app?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, wear-os

I have an app that runs fine on a phone, but I want to port it now to an Android Wear device. It will be a stand-alone app (no communication with a connected phone*). I was thinking to create a product flavor in my Gradle file to build the Wear application, as it will use a lot of the same code (communication with server, connection with devices, etc).

```
android {
    productFlavors {
       full {
           ... stuff for my phone app ...
       }
       wear {
           ... stuff for my wear app ...
       }
    }
}
```

I already run into problems with `dependencies`, but before I try to fix those issues, I want to know if this a viable scenario, or should I create a separate Wear-project?

*) It is a very specific use case, customer-specific. This will run on only one Wear device, and not be distributed through the Play Store.

Comment: For Android Wear 1.x apps you have to communicate with the phone app to get data. It sounds like you are trying to do Android Wear 2.x which is still in beta - so a separate project would make sense.

Comment: @MorrisonChang well, I did a separate app and it seems to work fine on my device (Polar M600), I can connect a Bluetooth device to it. I do have to use a phone for WiFi settings though.

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/app-distribution.html:

> Note that it currently is not possible to create a single APK that works on a phone and watch.

In other words, to "port" your app to Wear, you'll need to make changes such that it'll no longer run (satisfactorily) on a phone. You don't need a new project, but you do need a new module.

The advice that @apesoczi gave was correct for Wear 1.x, but not for Wear 2. It's perfectly legitimate (and, in fact, recommended) for a Wear 2 app to function completely standalone, without an associated handheld app. I'd advise that you read the first few sections at https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/standalone-apps.html; they'll give you a good overview of the issues involved in targeting both Wear 1 and 2 with your app.

Comment: I won't be targeting Wear 1 and 2, only one specific device which I have complete control over (it is part of a larger, industrial, system). I am also not looking for a single APK. What you say about another module in the project is what I was getting at. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from :https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

> When publishing to users, you must package a wearable app inside of a
>   handheld app, because users cannot browse and install apps directly on
>   the wearable. If packaged properly, when users download the handheld
>   app, the system automatically pushes the wearable app to the paired
>   wearable.

The answer to your question - No. Also, if your wearable is going to be pulling data from the server, your app should be doing this work and relaying the data to the wearable. I would strongly encourage you not to attempt to make a wearable app without a mobile app. Doing so is exactly against each and every development and design pattern, what I'm trying to say is, your signing up for your own worst nightmare.

Comment: Well, I have had quite some tech-nightmares, so I am up for it. The app will be prepackaged by us, on the device and not having a phone with it is an important part of the use case. As I said I will be using the wearable in a very small domain.